# Postman Interceptor and oAuth 2.0

Tags: postman

I am trying to use Postman to test APIs. I would like to use the currently active browser session within Postman to make the requests. I'm not sure how to do this. I have enabled Interceptor and I tried reading the Auth cookies but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

A browser's session doesn't give you all necessary data to login using oAuth 2.

You need to have Access Token, client ID, client secret, etc.

These data you have to input directly in Postman, you can't just take it from the current session in your browser.